# Rspec: How to suppress warnings and notices when running tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rspec2, rails-postgresql

I was using Mysql database before and decided to switch to Postgresql and now, when I run my tests using rspec, I getting a lot of warnings and notices.

```
WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
NOTICE:  there is no transaction in progress
      should has link "Suspender"
WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
NOTICE:  there is no transaction in progress
      should has css "title" with text "Suspensão de anúncio"
WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
NOTICE:  there is no transaction in progress
      should has css "h1" with text "Awesome job!"
```

How can I suppress that? Is there a way, right?

Comment: Are you calling it with the flag  `--format progress` ? maybe in your .rspec file?

Comment: No, I have only `--colour`, `--drb` and `--format d` on my .rspec file.

Comment: See: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/58 and consider using a DB cleaner as suggested in the issue.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already using `database_cleaner` gem.

Comment: Did you set: `config.use_transactional_examples = true` to false and see if that breaks anything?

Comment: Oh, setting `config.use_transaction_fixtures = false` stops the warnings and notices. Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Did you set: `config.use_transactional_examples = true` to false and see if that breaks anything?

Comment: where do we need to put this line? I tried in both config/environments/test.rb and config/application.rb. Still getting the warning messages

Comment: Hey, Got that. Updated that in spec/spec_helper.rb file

Comment: Finally, been looking at those ugly messages for too long. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` set.  This was default (spec_helper generated with `rails g rspec:install`).  I am using FactoryGirl instead of fixtures, getting rid of this setting removed warnings.

Answer (score 0):

> Disabling transactions
>
> If you prefer to manage the data yourself, or using another tool like
>   database_cleaner to do it for you, simply tell RSpec to tell Rails not to manage transactions:
>
> RSpec.configure do |config|
>     config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
>   end

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions