# Warning while testing specs on postgres: there is no transaction in progress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, postgresql, transactions

For each step of test occurs 2 lines:

```
WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
NOTICE:  there is no transaction in progress
```

With Spork lines following triples:

```
NOTICE:  there is no transaction in progress
NOTICE:  there is no transaction in progress
NOTICE:  there is no transaction in progress
WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
```

I don't know maybe it's important, just warned. GemFile:

```
group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'spork-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

all customized, so there is no need for develop group, and it not helps anyway. [this is spec_helper](https://gist.github.com/3744332).I found, that it is PostgreSQL feature, but I could not find how to fix it.
I will be grateful for the assistance

Comment: Your link to your `spec_helper.rb` seems to be broken. Which database cleaning strategy are you using? Transaction or truncation? If you're using the former, I might try the latter.

Comment: Thanks, I moved it to github gist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `spec_helper.rb`, I would try changing this

```
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end
```

to this

```
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end
```

Comment: That might be normal, depending on how many tests you have, and how many objects you're creating, and what you consider extremely slow.

Comment: But with this warning it works correctly, just my boss doesn't like it, i guess.

Comment: I would argue that if you're getting warnings and errors, it's not working correctly. How slow is your test suite? 30 seconds? 10 minutes? 4 hours?

Comment: I prefer to make this notes and warnings instead of waiting anyway.

Comment: Your test speed seems pretty much normal to me.

Comment: @Alder re truncation speed, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419536/postgresql-truncation-speed . Try PostgreSQL 9.2 and see if it's any faster.

Comment: I installed it, maybe it's faster, but it's to slow too.

Comment: There's seems to be prettier solution — http://stackoverflow.com/a/11068914/535406

Comment: FWIW I have about a thousands tests, the solution linked by @jibiel (set config.use_transactional_examples = false) runs 2.5x faster on my dev machine (mac, postgres, rails 3.0.17) than the solution by swett (set .strategy = truncation) -- specifically 3.5 minutes vs 8 minutes!

Comment: Hmm, I'd be curious to know whether that method actually utilizes a cleaning strategy at all. If so, the performance benefit would of course make it a better solution, but only if so, because a cleaning strategy is a must-have, in my opinion.

Comment: Short answer is Yes is still cleans: the test I ran is at the bottom of this blog post http://blog.pardner.com/2013/01/getting-rspec-postgres-databasecleaner-to-play-nicely-together/ which is modeled after http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-3/docs/transactional-examples

Answer (score 11):

In spec_helper.rb

```
config.use_transactional_examples = false #factoryGirl
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false #fixtures

config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end
```

In database.yml

```
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: myapp_test
  username: my_username
  password:
  allow_concurrency: true
  pool: 5
  min_messages: error
```

Even if you have set the min_messages option, you may still see console output like the following:

```
WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
```

Edit the file

```
/opt/local/var/db/postgresql92/defaultdb/postgresql.conf
```

and set the following:

```
client_min_messages = error
```

Everything should now be running smoothly.

Comment: config.use_transactional_examples = false

Worked for me.

Comment: config.use_transactional_fixtures = false #fixtures worked for me! :)